# Bizarre failure compiling hiredis dependency for redis: cc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, redis, compilation

I am trying to compile Redis 4.0.9 (latest) on Ubuntu 16.04. When running make in the redis directory, I get the following output:

```
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/src'
    CC Makefile.dep
rm -rf redis-server redis-sentinel redis-cli redis-benchmark redis-check-rdb redis-check-aof *.o *.gcda *.gcno *.gcov redis.info lcov-html Makefile.dep dict-benchmark
(cd ../deps && make distclean)
make[2]: Entering directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps'
(cd hiredis && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd linenoise && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd lua && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd jemalloc && [ -f Makefile ] && make distclean) > /dev/null || true
(rm -f .make-*)
make[2]: Leaving directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps'
(rm -f .make-*)
echo STD=-std=c99 -pedantic -DREDIS_STATIC='' >> .make-settings
echo WARN=-Wall -W -Wno-missing-field-initializers >> .make-settings
echo OPT=-O2 >> .make-settings
echo MALLOC=jemalloc >> .make-settings
echo CFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo LDFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo REDIS_CFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo REDIS_LDFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo PREV_FINAL_CFLAGS=-std=c99 -pedantic -DREDIS_STATIC='' -Wall -W -Wno-missing-field-initializers -O2 -g -ggdb   -I../deps/hiredis -I../deps/linenoise -I../deps/lua/src -DUSE_JEMALLOC -I../deps/jemalloc/include >> .make-settings
echo PREV_FINAL_LDFLAGS=  -g -ggdb -rdynamic >> .make-settings
(cd ../deps && make hiredis linenoise lua jemalloc)
make[2]: Entering directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps'
(cd hiredis && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd linenoise && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd lua && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd jemalloc && [ -f Makefile ] && make distclean) > /dev/null || true
(rm -f .make-*)
(echo "" > .make-cflags)
(echo "" > .make-ldflags)
MAKE hiredis
cd hiredis && make static
make[3]: Entering directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps/hiredis'
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -g -ggdb x86_64 net.c
cc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'net.o' failed
make[3]: *** [net.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps/hiredis'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'hiredis' failed
make[2]: *** [hiredis] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps'
Makefile:170: recipe for target 'persist-settings' failed
make[1]: [persist-settings] Error 2 (ignored)
    CC adlist.o
In file included from adlist.c:34:0:
zmalloc.h:50:31: fatal error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:228: recipe for target 'adlist.o' failed
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/user/HS104/m09170/redis/redis-4.0.9/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that the issue is to do with dependencies. If I go into the `deps` folder and manually compile the dependencies one by one, they all succeed (including jemalloc) except for hiredis, which gives the following output:

```
user@tefnut:~/redis/redis-4.0.9/deps/hiredis$ make
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -g -ggdb x86_64 net.c
cc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'net.o' failed
make: *** [net.o] Error 1
```

I've tried a `make distclean` to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was running:

`unset ARCH` and/or
`unset TARGET_ARCH`

after which hiredis compiled without complaints. I'm not sure *why* that works, so if anyone else knows why it makes a difference I am very curious.

Answer (score -1):

Install build-essential before making dependencies, gcc need to be installed there.

> sudo apt-get install build-essential